# how do I unit test a React component that inherits state from another component as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React app in which I have some state defined in the App component but which is populated in a child component and I'm having trouble creating a unit test using react-testing-library.  Here's the setup:

```js
// App.js

export default function App() {
    const [ programs, setPrograms ] = useState([]); 
    // list of programs to display in ProgramList.  Defined in this module so that is available in another module unrelated to ProgramList

    return <ProgramList programs={programs} setPrograms={setPrograms} />
}

// ProgramList.js

export default function ProgramList({programs, setPrograms}) {
    useEffect( () => loadPrograms(setPrograms), []);  
    // (this calls a service that uses axios to get the program list and then calls setPrograms to set the value)

    return <Select options={generateOptionListFromPrograms(programs)} />}
```

I'm trying to create a unit test for ProgramList, something like:

```js
// ProgramList.test.js

jest.mock('axios');

test('program list is fetched', async () => {
    const mockPrograms = [{name: "program1", label: "Program 1"}, {name: "program2", label: "Program 2"}]
    const promise = Promise.resolve({data: mockPrograms});
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => promise);

    // something like...  but what do i put in for setPrograms?
    render(<ProgramList setPrograms={???} programs={???} />);
    // I tried putting in
    //  const[ programs, setPrograms ] = useState([]); // in this function and passing the programs
    // and setPrograms to ProgramList but I can't call useState in a test function
});
```

Or is my whole approach broken and I need to actually have my useEffect in App.js?  That would work but it feels wrong - I would rather populate the list closer to where it is being used.  I have other similar lists in my app that will need to get populated and I'm not too happy about putting all those useEffects in App.js.

Comment: Most likely you need to wrap your ProgramList component in a basic function component that lets you use the `useState` hook. It's not unheard of to have a few such "helper" components in your tests.

Comment: Thanks - that was a great idea (why didn't I think of that?).